# question in sql server 2005 Proc

Tags: sql-server

i have this  Proc

```
CREATE Proc  [dbo].Salse_Ditail 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Report_Form  varchar(1)  ,
    @DateFrom datetime  ,
    @DateTo  datetime   ,
    @COMPANYID varchar(3),
    @All varchar(1) ,
    @All1 varchar(1)    , 
    @All2 varchar(1)   , 
    @All3 varchar(1)   ,
    @All4 varchar(1)  , 
    @All5 varchar(1)   ,  
    @Sector varchar(10),
    @Report_Parameter nvarchar(max)  
as
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    DECLARE @STRWhere nvarchar(max)

    IF @All5=0 AND @All4=0 AND @All3=0 AND @All2=0 AND @All1=0 and @All=1
        set @STRWhere=  N'and  Sector_id = @Sector' 

    if @Report_Form =1 or @Report_Form =3 or @Report_Form =4 

    SELECT   RETURNREASONCODEID, SITE,SITE_NAME,Factory_id,Factory_Name,Sector_id,sector_name,Customer_name,
         Customer_id,ITEMID,ITEMNAME,SALESMANID,SALESMAN_NAME,Net_Qty,Net_Salse,Gross_Sales,Gross_Qty,
         NETWEIGHT_Gross,NETWEIGHT_salse_Gross,NETWEIGHT_NET,NETWEIGHT_salse_NET,Return_Sales,Free_Good,
         CollectionAmount  

    FROM hal_bas_new_rep 

    WHERE   DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID AND INVOICEDATE >= @DateFrom 
        AND INVOICEDATE <= @DateTo and Report_Activti = @Report_Form 

    if  @Report_Form =2  

        SELECT   RETURNREASONCODEID ,  RETURNREASONDESC,  SITE , SITE_NAME , Factory_id ,
            Factory_Name ,  Sector_id ,  sector_name ,  Customer_name ,  Customer_id , 
            ITEMID , ITEMNAME , SALESMANID , SALESMAN_NAME ,    Return_Sales   

        FROM dbo.hal_bas_new_rep 

        WHERE  DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID AND INVOICEDATE >= @DateFrom 
            AND INVOICEDATE <= @DateTo and Report_Activti =   @Report_Form 
            and  RETURNREASONCODEID in
            (
                SELECT     Val 
                FROM dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@Report_Parameter,',',1)
            )  
            /*
            @STRWhere   question how i can but the virble here  
            */
end
GO
```

i want to <strike>but virble</strike> put a variable under where Expression and from this function 
buc I have many function i want to add

if any one have answer pls send me

Comment: What does, "iwant to but virble under where Expression," mean?

Comment: I think virble is "variable" ?  maybe he meant "... put variable under where expression... " ?"

Comment: thanks for answer

i try but not work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to construct a dynamic SQL Statement and then execute it...   part of it (the where clause)  is to use the string/text content of the variable @STRWhere.

What you want to check out is the `Execute` statement and the system stored procedure called `sp_ExecuteSQL()`

but you could also rewrite proc like this and do the same thing:

```
  If @Report_Form In (1,3,4)      
    SELECT RETURNREASONCODEID, SITE, SITE_NAME, 
           Factory_id, Factory_Name, Sector_id, 
          sector_name,Customer_name, Customer_id, 
          ITEMID, ITEMNAME, SALESMANID, SALESMAN_NAME, 
          Net_Qty, Net_Salse, Gross_Sales,G ross_Qty,               
          NETWEIGHT_Gross, NETWEIGHT_salse_Gross, 
          NETWEIGHT_NET, NETWEIGHT_salse_NET, 
          Return_Sales,Free_Good, CollectionAmount  
    FROM hal_bas_new_rep  
    WHERE DATAAREAID = @COMPANYID 
        And INVOICEDATE Between @DateFrom And @DateTo 
        And Report_Activti = @Report_Form  

  If  @Report_Form =2   
     SELECT RETURNREASONCODEID, RETURNREASONDESC, SITE, 
         SITE_NAME, Factory_id, Factory_Name,  Sector_id,
         sector_name,  Customer_name,  Customer_id,  
         ITEMID, ITEMNAME, SALESMANID, SALESMAN_NAME,    
         Return_Sales    
     FROM dbo.hal_bas_new_rep  
     WHERE DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID 
       And INVOICEDATE Between @DateFrom And @DateTo 
       And Report_Activti = @Report_Form  
       And RETURNREASONCODEID in
            (SELECT Val From dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@Report_Parameter,',',1))   
       And Sector_id = Case When @All=1 And @All5+@All4+@All3+@All2=+@All1=0 
               Then @Sector Else Sector_id End
```

end

Comment: thanks for answer but i want to Illustration in a more 
i DECLARE @STRWhere as  5tring virble to be text between Landmark to 

set @STRWhere=  'and  Sector_id = @Sector'  

IF @All5=0 AND @All4=0 AND @All3=0 AND @All2=0 AND @All1=0 and @All=1 
        set @STRWhere=  N'and  Sector_id = @Sector'  

i want to put this 'and  Sector_id = @Sector'  after the where is finish under the  if function  if under the  if function   is ' ' 
the function not read 

thanks for all pls 
if find answer send to me

Comment: As I mentioned, to do this, you have to create the entire SQL statement as a string variable, and then execute it as a complete sql statement using the `Execute` statement, or the `sp_SqlExecute()` stored procedure.  You cannot add or combine the contents of a string variable to a explicit partial sql statement and execute it.

Comment: sp_ExecuteSQL @   http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=sp_ExecuteSQL&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CQ2ag-SgWTJPiIoLeNdT_0MkKAAAAqgQFT9ApnGw